# How can I animate/draw a line renderer over a given period of time

Tags: unity

I have created a line renderer using the code below:

```
public class MyLineRenderer : MonoBehaviour {
LineRenderer lineRenderer;

public Vector3 p0, p1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.positionCount = 2; 

    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, p0);
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, p1);

    }
}
```

How can I write a coroutine that will animate/draw the line over specific duration, say 2 seconds?

Comment: Can someone please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LineRenderer lineRenderer;
private float distance;
private float counter;

public Vector3 p0, p1;
public float lineDrawSpeed = 6f;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    lineRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, p0);

    distance = Vector3.Distance(p0, p1);

}

void Update()
{

    if (counter < distance)
    {
        counter += .1f / lineDrawSpeed;
        float x = Mathf.Lerp(0, distance, counter);
        var point0 = p0;
        var point1 = p1;

        var pointALongLine= x * Vector3.Normalize(point1 - point0) + point0;

        lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, pointALongLine);
    }

}
```

Comment: Here is the video source [Animate a line draw using Line Renderer Component](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bqcu94VuVOI)

Comment: @chronos did the answer above help you?